# On page load set a certain style to a LI element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a page with the following menu:

https://jsfiddle.net/dva4zo8t/

Based on which menu button is clicked, the color changes and I can "remember" (set) the color on a new page load, like so:

```
$('[id*="button"]').click(function() {
    $('.topmenu-ul li').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('topmenu-selected' + $('a', this).attr('class'));
});
```

I also want to set a style to the LI element (a different background color and a red highlighted text) once the page loads. So, when I click on "New Appointment", on the new page, the LI element should look like this:

[image: example]

So what I basically want is to change the class of the sub li just as I do with the main buttons, for example:

```
$('#redbutton').addClass('topmenu-selectedred');
$('.topmenu-tab-appointments').show();
```

Comment: You want same color to the submenu also?

Comment: I actually want the submenu background to be the same as when you hover a subitem. It's a slightly different color.

Comment: actually am not getting your requirement.. When you hover a submenu you want to change the background color is that it?

Comment: No. When I click on "New Appointment", my "new appointment" page loads. Then I want to automatically change the style on the menu of "New Appointment" like in the above image. Text should be changed to red and the background color should be changed as well, to keep it simple, let's say to white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve created a fiddle that will make the buttons turn it´s background when pushed.

then you will make to them tu "unpush" when others are pushed.

try this fiddle.

```js
    $(".topmenu-ul li").click(function() {
      $('li > #topmenu-ul').hide();
      $(this).children("ul").toggle();
    });

    $('[id*="button"]').click(function() {
      $('.topmenu-ul li').removeClass();
      $(this).addClass('topmenu-selected' + $('a', this).attr('class'));
    });

    $('.topmenu-ul li a').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('topmenu-selectedsub');
    });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
header,
footer,
article,
section,
hgroup,
nav,
figure {
  display: block
}
body {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #f8f4eb;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/*
 *  HTML5 Sections
 */

.header {
  height: 72px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
  min-height: calc(100% - 124px);
  background-color: #f8f4eb;
}
.aside {
  float: left;
  width: 195px;
  background-color: #ebddca;
  height: 100%;
}
/*
 *  Top Menu Styles
 */

.topmenu {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#858585, #636263);
  border-top: 1px solid #656565;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3663ab;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #a8a8a8;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000
}
.topmenu-header {
  height: 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5efe4 0%, #d3cdbe 100%);
  border-top: 1px solid #d5cab8
}
.topmenu-subbg {
  padding-left: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  top: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c8bfb0 0px, #f5efe6 7px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3c7b6
}
.topmenu-ul,
li,
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.topmenu-ul li {
  list-style: none
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000
}
.topmenu-ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #414141;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 rgba(165, 162, 165, 1)
}
.topmenu-ul > li a {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: .7rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px
}
.topmenu-ul > li a:hover {
  color: #fff
}
.topmenu-ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f3efe5
}
.topmenu-ul li ul {
  font-size: 0;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: -8px;
}
.topmenu-ul li ul li a {
  color: #000;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.topmenu-ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.topmenu-ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c8bfb0 0px, #f5efe6 7px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3c7b6;
  border-right: 1px solid #d5ccbe
}
.topmenu-ul > [class*=topmenu-selected] > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.topmenu-selectedblue {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#78b1ff, #4881dc)
}
.topmenu-selectedred {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff8476, #dc5348)
}
.topmenu-selectedpurple {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#b479ff, #854ade)
}
.topmenu-selectedgreen {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9dd592, #649f5a)
}
.topmenu-selectedsub {
  background-color: #f3efe5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="topmenu-header"></div>
  <div class="topmenu">
    <ul class="topmenu-ul">
      <li id="bluebutton"><a class="blue">Home</a>

        <ul id="topmenu-ul" class="topmenu-tab-home">
          <li><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="redbutton"><a class="red">Appointments</a>

        <ul id="topmenu-ul" class="topmenu-tab-appointments">
          <li><a href="#">Appointments</a>
          </li>
          <li><a id="new" href="#">New Appointment</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="greenbutton"><a class="green">Contacts</a>

        <ul id="topmenu-ul" class="topmenu-tab-contacts">
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">New Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**EDIT**

Anyway, if you want to do it after page is loaded, you can use [document.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //JUST ADD AN ID TO THE BUTTON AND THIS WILL CHANGE IT´S BACKGROUND AFTER PAGE LOADS
   $("#new").addClass('topmenu-selectedsub');
});
```

There is the demo:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //JUST ADD AN ID TO THE BUTTON AND THIS WILL CHANGE IT´S BACKGROUND AFTER PAGE LOADS
  $('#new').addClass('topmenu-selectedsub');
   $('.topmenu-tab-appointments').show();

});


$(".topmenu-ul li").click(function() {
  $('li > #topmenu-ul').hide();
  $(this).children("ul").toggle();
});

$('[id*="button"]').click(function() {
  $('.topmenu-ul li').removeClass();
  $(this).addClass('topmenu-selected' + $('a', this).attr('class'));
});

$('.topmenu-ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('topmenu-selectedsub');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
header,
footer,
article,
section,
hgroup,
nav,
figure {
  display: block
}
body {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  background-color: #f8f4eb;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
/*
 *  HTML5 Sections
 */

.header {
  height: 72px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
  min-height: calc(100% - 124px);
  background-color: #f8f4eb;
}
.aside {
  float: left;
  width: 195px;
  background-color: #ebddca;
  height: 100%;
}
/*
 *  Top Menu Styles
 */

.topmenu {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#858585, #636263);
  border-top: 1px solid #656565;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3663ab;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #a8a8a8;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000
}
.topmenu-header {
  height: 4px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5efe4 0%, #d3cdbe 100%);
  border-top: 1px solid #d5cab8
}
.topmenu-subbg {
  padding-left: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  top: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c8bfb0 0px, #f5efe6 7px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3c7b6
}
.topmenu-ul,
li,
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.topmenu-ul li {
  list-style: none
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000
}
.topmenu-ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #414141;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 rgba(165, 162, 165, 1)
}
.topmenu-ul > li a {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  font-size: .7rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px
}
.topmenu-ul > li a:hover {
  color: #fff
}
.topmenu-ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f3efe5
}
.topmenu-ul li ul {
  font-size: 0;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: -8px;
}
.topmenu-ul li ul li a {
  color: #000;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.topmenu-ul li ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.topmenu-ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c8bfb0 0px, #f5efe6 7px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3c7b6;
  border-right: 1px solid #d5ccbe
}
.topmenu-ul > [class*=topmenu-selected] > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.topmenu-selectedblue {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#78b1ff, #4881dc)
}
.topmenu-selectedred {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff8476, #dc5348)
}
.topmenu-selectedpurple {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#b479ff, #854ade)
}
.topmenu-selectedgreen {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9dd592, #649f5a)
}
.topmenu-selectedsub {
  background-color: #f3efe5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="topmenu-header"></div>
  <div class="topmenu">
    <ul class="topmenu-ul">
      <li id="bluebutton"><a class="blue">Home</a>

        <ul id="topmenu-ul" class="topmenu-tab-home">
          <li><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="redbutton"><a class="red">Appointments</a>

        <ul id="topmenu-ul" class="topmenu-tab-appointments">
          <li><a href="#">Appointments</a>
          </li>
          <li><a id="new" href="#">New Appointment</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="greenbutton"><a class="green">Contacts</a>

        <ul id="topmenu-ul" class="topmenu-tab-contacts">
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">New Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, accepting this answer since it directly answered my question, however I still am going to see if I can do this server side in a cleaner way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To do this you would normally use a sever side language to set a class on loading the page (i.e; on the About page add the class `about-page` to body, or the class `current` to the about link). But to do it with jQuery only you would need to know the urls of the pages.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  
  var $links = $('nav a'),
      
      links_array = [],
      
      current_url = window.location.pathname,
      
      current_link_idx;
  
  // we dont have an actual url so we'll pretend here 
  // for the sake of the snippet/preview
  current_url = '/about';
  
  
  $links.each(function(){
    links_array.push($(this).attr('href'));
  });
  
  current_link_idx = links_array.indexOf(current_url);
  
  $links.eq(current_link_idx).addClass('current-page');
  
});
```

```css
.current-page {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="/etc">Etc</a>
</nav>
```

Obviously, if you have complex nav/urls, this isn't bulletproof. You'll need to do some fiddling with the `current_url`, maybe splitting it into fragments.

Still, this is best done server side.

Comment: Server side, gotcha. I am using laravel so I think I will be able to figure this out and do it properly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

See this working [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dva4zo8t/5/)

```
 $(".topmenu-ul li").click(function() {
        $('li > #topmenu-ul').hide();
        $(this).children("ul").toggle();
        $(".topmenu-ul li").css("background-color","")
        $(this).css("background-color","red")
    });
$('[id*="button"]').click(function() {
        $('.topmenu-ul li').removeClass();
        $(this).addClass('topmenu-selected' + $('a', this).attr('class'));

    });

    $("#topmenu-ul li a").click(function() {


        $("#topmenu-ul li a").css("background-color","")
        $(this).css("background-color","red")
    });
```

You can put whatever **color** you like to add. Its upto you , I have just shown you how to do it

Comment: Doesn't this simply add the color once I click on the link? Once I click on a link and it goes to the next page, the color is removed again. I want to be able to set a color AFTER the page loads. So basically, I want to add a class to a LI element I specify on each page, like so: `$('#redbutton').addClass('topmenu-selectedred');`

Comment: @RonBrouwers : for that you have to check in a loop for all `li` > `a` `href`== current page directory ...if its each that set a color for that... and all these will be in `$(window).load()`  .. r u getting me ?